# how to output AVAsset (over 500mb) and write it to a new file in a path,ex: NSTemporaryDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, avasset

I want to upload a big AVAsset (over 500mb) by using NSURLSession(file).
first, I need to copy an avasset and write it into a temp path,

```
filePath = [(AVURLAsset *)avasset URL];
    // file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1067.MOV

NSFileHandle *fileReadHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
NSData *data = [fileReadHandle readDataToEndOfFile];

// No longer using the file
[fileReadHandle closeFile];

NSFileHandle *fileWriteHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:tempFile];

// add some header information for upload use        
[fileWriteHandle writeData:@"some information for upload"];

// Write in tempFile
[fileWriteHandle writeData:data];
[fileWriteHandle synchronizeFile];// Flush any data in memory to disk
```

and the data size is 0, why?

Comment: Don't see where fileWriteHandle is created/initialized.  In any case, check if data is actually read (ie., non-zero)  400meg is pretty big chunk to read all at once on a mobile device.

Comment: sorry I just pasted part of my code, updated my post.
do you know how to use fileHandle to write file by using smaller chunk?

I know [rep getBytes:chunkBuffer fromOffset:offset length:chunkSize error:nil];
but now I use AVAsset, I don't know how to do..